# convert dynamic number of rows to fixed number of columns

Tags: excel

I need to convert dynamic number of rows to fixed number of columns. how to do it? Here is what I want to do:

```
A1      B1      C1
A2      B2      C3
        B3
```

convert to

```
A1      A2          
B1      B2      B3
C1              C3
```

assuming there are 3 colomns total in the result table.

Thanks

Comment: But there was a mistake in the originalquestion

Comment: I believe you noted the mistake, in the comments. You could also edit the question. I would definitely discourage you from creating (near) duplicates. They will likely be closed. I also encourage you to clarify your original question, as I still don't understand how you would treat different numbers of rows. I know your before and after seems clear to you, but it's not to me. Welcome to SO and good luck!

Comment: @user2489186 .. at least you could delete your earlier question